# Rails 4 - Problemas com has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails4

preciso de ajuda para exibir na view o valor na view de um relacionamento com o has_many.

Tenho meu model de produtos:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
paginates_per 15

has_many :product_images, :dependent => :delete_all
```

Estou fazendo um find neste model:

```
@products = Product.where(:active => 1).includes(:product_images)
```

Mas não consigo fazer por exemplo

```
@product.image_products.id
```

O que está errado? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Quando voce utiliza o has_many, ele irá retornar um array de objetos, ou seja, se voce chamar apenas o '.id', ele não permitirá, pois o '.id' é o atributo de um objeto, e ele não conseguirá pegá-lo se você fizer em um array...

Contudo, se voce deseja os ids dos objetos, que acho que é o que voce precisaria neste caso, voce poderia utilizar o método 'pluck', este método irá retornar por exemplo, todos aquele atributo de todos os arrays daquele objeto... ficaria mais ou menos assim...

```
@product.image_products.pluck(:id)
```

No rails 4, voce só conseguirá pegar nesse caso um atributo por vês, já no rails 5, permite voce fazer um pluck de 2 atributos daqueles objetos, o que torna a função bem mais interessante...

Espero que tenha ajudado, valeu!!

Comment: obrigado ajudou sim estava quebrando a cabeça, mas está solução foi bastante útil. Mas mesmo no rails 5 como você mencionou que é possível passar 2 atributos achei ainda um pouco limitado.